# JQuery: How to apply function to hash values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have some simple hash, like:

```
var hash = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
```

I'd like to create a new hash, by applying some function to the above hash's values, such as:

```
var new_hash = {"a":2, "b":4, "c":6}
```

I know to do this, for example, in *ruby*:

```
new_hash = hash.inject({}) { |h, (k, v)| h[k] = 2*v; h }
```

...But I can't work out the correct syntax for an equivalent operation in JQuery! From what I've read online, I believe the answer may involve the use of `.makeArray()` and `.map()`, but I just can't get it to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamruss/4kB5e/1/). 
open dev console to see the output

```
var hash = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
var new_hash = {};
jQuery.each(hash, function(idx){ 
    console.log(idx);
    new_hash[idx] = this*2;})
console.log(new_hash);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop would do it:

```
var hash = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3};
for (var i in hash) {
    hash[i] *= 2;
}
console.log(hash);
```

You could however use `.forEach` in combination with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` (which would handle the key names as an array) like so:

```
var hash = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3};
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(hash).forEach(function(name) {
    hash[name] *= 2;
});
console.log(hash);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
var hash = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3};
var new_hash = {};
$.each( hash, function( key,val ) {
    new_hash[key] = 2 * val;
});
console.log(new_hash); //Object { a=2, b=4, c=6}
```

or

```
var hash = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3};
var new_hash = $.extend.apply(null, $.map(hash, function(val,idx) { var h = {}; h[idx] = val * 2; return h }));
console.log(new_hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are lookgin for the [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. Or if you really want the jQuery function, its [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)